# Integral transforms and uncertainty products

Tags: integral-transforms

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle is well-studied and has become a bit of a pop science phenomenon due to its widespread implications in quantum mechanics. (Though interpretations are often misrepresented.) The Heisenberg uncertainty principle can be arrived at in a couple of ways:

1. By considering the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, noting that equality only holds for eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform, knowing *a priori* what the eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform are and then minimizing the uncertainty product over all eigenfunctions. (The minimizer being the Gaussian of course.)
2. Considering commutators of the position and momentum operators.

Many integral transforms that I have come across have uncertainty products associated to them. In the case of the Fourier transform it's not so hard to see since scaling in one domain causes an inverse scaling in the conjugate domain so that the more localized a function is, the more spread out its Fourier transform is. My question is: is this an accident? Or is there something intrinsic about integral transforms on the whole that somehow naturally encodes uncertainty products?

Answer (score 1):

Once i almost had a fight with one of my professors on mathematics because i maintained that this is **not** accidental.

The point is to have an understanding of what the fourier transform *means* for a signal or system and then how this relates to momentum (at least in QM).

Since fourier transforms (or integral representations in other domains) are used heavily in **real-world** applications, it is important.

The intuition is that a *signal* (or *measurement*) **cannot** be **localized** (arbitrarily and at the same *point*) in both domains. Roughly because the information for a *point* at one domain **depends** on information of multiple *points* of the other (this is what a linear integral transform does). Mathematically this is expressed as an inequality (upper bound) of the *uncertainties* of both *points* and the correlation between the *measurements* (also called [fourier uncertainty principle](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Du.pdf)).

Furthermore one can say that the two measurements **cannot** be represented **exactly** on the the same basis (or that the *measurements* **do not** commute).

Comment: I agree entirely and in the Fourier case, it's manifest but I guess I was speaking in much more generality than just the Fourier case. The argument to real world phenomena is a little impervious in the general case. However it does serve as a good guide to go by.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, of course there is variety of integral transforms. However in the case of fourier (or others, eg [short-time fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)), this is very clear. There are other transforms that use different [kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform), e.g [Wigner distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_distribution_function) [etc..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%E2%80%93frequency_analysis), yet what they do is interchange localization in one domain for the other.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, much in this discussion also depends on one's view (or affiliation) with specific interpretations of QM (which was at least part of my *almost fight*). Nevertheless it still a valid argument. (ps. i dont like the offical interpretation too much myself)

Comment: @CameronWilliams, one point missing (or rather not fully elaborated) in the answer, is why (or how) momentum relates to fourier transform and why it is needed (in QM). This needs a much longer analysis. Shortly, fourier transform encodes information about the group structure and group characters (for example: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/reu02/fourier.pdf, http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf)

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of dual groups and such but I think that you have cause and effect backwards. The general case was motivated by the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, i'm not sure  i understand what you mean, cause and effect backwards, in any case check also [this post about transforms in general and how they relate to one-another](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/856741/139391)

Comment: @CameronWilliams, im not sure i reverse "cause-effect", the full answer to this, is the reason (in QM) the momentum is the fourier transform of the position (which in clasical case is the legendre transform), previous comment gives an answer in this direction, a full answer requires a little more, but still i would not say i reverse cause or effect or anything of the like